# In what ways do Muslim women show ingratitude to their spouses?

Tags: hadith, women, hadith-interpretation, husband-wife

My question is in regards to this hadith:

> Jabir b. 'Abdullah reported:  ... He then walked on till **he came to the women and preached to them and admonished them, and asked them to give alms**, for most of them are the fuel for Hell. A woman having a dark spot on the cheek stood up and said: Why is it so, Messenger of Allah? He said: **For you grumble often and show ingratitude to your spouse.** ... -- Sahih Muslim 885 b ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/8/4))

**Question**: In what ways do Muslim women show ingratitude to their spouses?

I'd like to identify common examples of how women show ingratitude to their spouses, so as to better mental picture of the circumstances in which the hadith applies, and so that I can avoid showing ingratitude myself (if inshallah I find a suitable husband).

Perhaps it's just long-term nagging and nit-picking, or maybe there's more to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained by the Prophet ﷺ in a [*Hadeeth* recorded in Saheeh Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/22) on the authority of 'Abdullah ibn 'Abbaas:

> "I was shown the Hell-fire and that the majority of its dwellers were women who were ungrateful." It was asked, "Do they disbelieve in Allah?" (or are they ungrateful to Allah?) He replied, "They are ungrateful to their husbands and are ungrateful for the favors and the good (charitable deeds) done to them. If you have always been good (benevolent) to one of them and then she sees something in you (not of her liking), she will say, 'I have never received any good from you."

And in part of [another (lengthier) *Hadeeth*](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/131) recorded by Bukhari, also narrated by Ibn Abbaas, the Prophet ﷺ is reported to have said:

> Then I saw the (Hell) Fire, and I have never before, seen such a horrible sight as that, and I saw that the majority of its dwellers were women." The people asked, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! What is the reason for that?" He replied, "Because of their ungratefulness." It was said. "Do they disbelieve in Allah (are they ungrateful to Allah)?" He replied, "They are not thankful to their husbands and are ungrateful for the favors done to them. Even if you do good to one of them all your life, when she seems some harshness from you, she will say, "I have never seen any good from you.' "