# How can a wife express gratitude to her husband?

Tags: nikah, women, husband-wife

I'm thinking about the flip side of this question: [In what ways do Muslim women show ingratitude to their spouses?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37645/17163).  According to Sahih Muslim, the Prophet said that women generally show ingratitude to their spouses.

**Question**: How can a wife express gratitude to her husband?

Put yourself in the shoes of a Muslim woman who's just read this hadith, and wants to make an effort to show gratitude, and is thinking *but what do I do?*

I'm guessing something like not being up tight about things, or being more responsive to sexual acts, might count.  Or maybe this is more of a general attitude towards him.  It's unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

When two people meet, we have different narrations saying that the elder should greet first, while also we have narrations which say the younger should greet first. Islam tries to always keep *both* sides satisfied

If I don't speak of what men must also do, my answer would look terribly unbalanced...so I'll partially include what men must do.

A women should have **obedience** towards her husband while a husband must have **camaraderie** for her wife.

Assuming the husband doesn't have time or for whatever reason can't take her wife out for dinner the wife should be cool about it. At the same time if the wife asks, the husband should do his best to please his wife and take her out for shopping/dinner.

When a husband gets home late, the wife shouldn't be like why did you come home late, I had to deal with the kids all by myself and clean after, she should be welcoming with with minimum a glass of water...At the same time the husband should do his best to get home early... if needed he would have to wake up an hour earlier to be able to do such...

But as you mentioned yourself, be sexually responsive ie put on good makeup and make herself appealing...but then again the husband should also clean himself up, make his wife enjoy bed with her. The prophet said I don't like men who just jump on their wives like an eagle to its prey...husbands and wives should also both try stay fit or physically appealing to their spouse.

Other things that come to mind might be to bare with him financially, don't ask what he can't do, like don't push him to buy things just because your other friends are also buying...it would humiliate him. Keep the house warm with her kindness and patience, do things for Allah, not because she expects something in return, be patient with him because of Allah.

Be patient for his *غیره* (shame for her showing her beauty) ie if says speak with more Haya' *حیا* then do so (but then again men should also give full attention to their wives, many men come home and just watch TV, open their iPhones and barely ask their wives what went on, they should make eye contact will talking, show focus and attention...it shouldn't be like "I wasn't listening...what were you saying?").

Be a loving mother for his and her children, teach them what they need to be taught and protect them from all the wrong teachings.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the husband, Different men like different things. Find out what your husband really appreciates. Maybe when you wear a beautiful dress, or underwear. It could be something small as well, such as a kiss and a simple; "thank you my love!"

Comment: This looks like a typical post in an internet forum, we are a Q&A site (see [answer]).